# looking for parameter help with filemaker "list" function

Tags: filemaker

I'm trying to get the following equation to return the results comma separated on a single line.  Right now it leaves out the commas and puts each result on a separate line.  I've tried with and without the paragraph symbol.

List (If ( ${1} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 1 ; "1" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${2} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 2 ; "2" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${3} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 3 ; "3" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${4} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 4 ; "4" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${5} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 5 ; "5" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${6} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 6 ; "6" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${7} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 7 ; "7" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${8} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 8 ; "8" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${9} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 9 ; "9" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${10} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 10 ; "10" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${11} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 11 ; "11" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${12} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 12 ; "12" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${13} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 13 ; "13" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${14} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 14 ; "14" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${15} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 15 ; "15" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${16} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 16 ; "16" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${17} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 17 ; "17" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${18} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 18 ; "18" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${19} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 19 ; "19" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${20} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 20 ; "20" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${21} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 21 ; "21" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${22} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 22 ; "22" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${23} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 23 ; "23" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${24} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 24 ; "24" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${25} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 25 ; "25" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${26} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 26 ; "26" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${27} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 27 ; "27" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${28} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 28 ; "28" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${29} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 29 ; "29" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${30} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 30 ; "30" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${31} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 31 ; "31" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${32} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 32 ; "32" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${33} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 33 ; "33" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${34} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 34 ; "34" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${35} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 35 ; "35" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${36} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 36 ; "36" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${37} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 37 ; "37" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${38} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 38 ; "38" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${39} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 39 ; "39" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${40} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 40 ; "40" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${41} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 40 ; "41" ; "" ) ;

If ( ${42} = "Spare" and panelSize ≥ 42 ; "42" ; "" ) ;  ¶ ;  ", " )

The result returns each entry on it's own line with no comma.  I tried it with and without the  ¶.

Comment: Can you paste the entire calc?  It looks like you're missing the "Substitute" from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Your list function puts them all into a list, and also puts the pilcrow ( ¶ ) and the ", " in the list as well.  The other suggestion to use Substitute was close but not quite.  Leave the List there, but add a Substitute to the start.

Substitute ( List ( allyourvalueshere ) ; ¶ ; ", " )

This takes your list and changes all the returns to commas.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "substitute" function before the "list" function.